# Nothing apear in UIcollectionView Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have UIcollectionView in my first view of application after Uinavigationviewcontroller just in storyboard just like this :

[image]

this is my RootViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface RootViewController : UICollectionViewController<UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *entries;
 @end
```

and my RootViewController.m :

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "AppRecord.h"
#import "Cell.h"
#define kCustomRowCount     7


@interface RootViewController () <UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
// the set of IconDownloader objects for each app
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *imageDownloadsInProgress;
@end


@implementation RootViewController

#pragma mark 

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  viewDidLoad
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 NSLog(@"inside class");
    [super viewDidLoad];
   // self.title = @"My Title";

    //self.collectionView.delegate = self;
    //self.collectionView.dataSource=self;

}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSUInteger count = [self.entries count];
    NSLog(@"count: %lu", (unsigned long)count);

    if (count == 0)
    {
        return kCustomRowCount;
    }
    return count;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"inside cell");
    AppRecord *appRecord = [self.entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Cell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MY_CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImage *truckImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    truckImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
    cell.imageView.image = truckImage;
    return cell;
}

@end
```

now problem is none of my "cellForItemAtIndexPath" or "numberOfItemsInSection" or even "viewDidLoad" getting called and the output on Simulator is black screen.

This is my reload section of AppDelegate class :

```
    __block ParseOperation *weakParser = parser;

    parser.completionBlock = ^(void) {
        if (weakParser.appRecordList) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController*)[(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController topViewController];

                rootViewController.entries = weakParser.appRecordList;
                if(weakParser.appRecordList != nil)
                    NSLog(@"weakParser.appRecordList is Not nill");
                [rootViewController.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[rootViewController.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]];
                [rootViewController.collectionView reloadData];
            });
        }

        self.queue = nil;
    };

    [self.queue addOperation:parser];
    self.appListData = nil;
}
```

Comment: Start with a tutorial on Ray Wenderlich. There are literally hundreds of places to go to find this out. When you get stuck with them then come here. You need to learn how they work first though.

Comment: i have no problem with uitableview and ive done everything mentioned in "Ray Wenderlich" tutorial like this one :
http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12
dont know why i stuck badly here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add the delegate and datasource connection for the collection view? It's the most common mistake, usually. They're commented out in code, I assume you did that via Storyboard

Comment: yes ive done both , but nothing happend then i commented the lines.
im using lazyloading appdelegate to reload collectionview data :
        [rootViewController.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[rootViewController.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]];
        [rootViewController.collectionView reloadData];

Comment: You're right, I usually don't use UICollectionViewControllers since I find UIViewControllers with embedded collection view more flexible. When are you calling those methods in AppDelegate? They need to be called AFTER RootViewController's viewDidLoad

Comment: thanks for suggestion , my problem is "viewDidLoad" or "viewWillApear" not getting called inside my rootviewcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have identifier on the storyboard cell?You can try to add

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MY_CELL"];
```

in viewDidLoad

Since your RootViewController inherit UICollectionViewController you don't need to add UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout at all

Comment: thanks for suggestion , yes i have set identifier for my cell in storyboard. problem is none of "viewDidLoad" or "viewWillApear" gets called in my class.

Comment: This can happen if you have set wrong class in the storyboard, since it is only one class i doubt it is wrong.Try to restart the xCode and set viewController's class again